# Resolving template name conflicts between subprojects and root projects in Play 2 Java Framework

Tags: java, templates, module, playframework, playframework-2.0

When using subprojects as part of a Play 2 project, it seems that if the main project and a sub project each a have a template with the same name, say `navtop.scala.html` and you call an import into another template within the subproject, the app chooses the template from the main project.

Is it possible to specify the 'local' template for import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Play compiles Scala template files to real classes. So app/views/navtop.scala.html will be compiled to views.html.navtop. It is a bad practice to have two classes with the same fully qualified name and mess around with class loaders. To prevent class file clashes use packages.

It is no requirement of play to put all views into the folder app/views. You can also use for example app/admin/views/navtop.scala.html which will be compiled to admin.views.html.navtop which is different from views.html.navtop.

To import it in a template:

```
@import admin.views.html.navtop

@navtop()
```

If it still collides use the full name, e.g. `return ok(admin.views.html.navtop.render());`.